# pandas split one column into multiple KeyError

Tags: python, pandas, split

```
df = age;"job";"marital";"education";"default";"housing";"loan";"contact";"month";"day_of_week";"duration";"campaign";"pdays";"previous";"poutcome";"emp.var.rate";"cons.price.idx";"cons.conf.idx";"euribor3m";"nr.employed";"y"
0  30;"blue-collar";"married";"basic.9y";"no";"ye...                                                                                                                                                                          
1  39;"services";"single";"high.school";"no";"no"...                                                                                                                                                                          
2  25;"services";"married";"high.school";"no";"ye...                                                                                                                                                                          
3  38;"services";"married";"basic.9y";"no";"unkno...                                                                                                                                                                          
4  47;"admin.";"married";"university.degree";"no"...                                                                                                                                                                          
5  32;"services";"single";"university.degree";"no...                                                                                                                                                                          
6  32;"admin.";"single";"university.degree";"no";...                                                                                                                                                                          
7  41;"entrepreneur";"married";"university.degree...                                                                                                                                                                          
8  31;"services";"divorced";"professional.course"...                                                                                                                                                                          
9  35;"blue-collar";"married";"basic.9y";"unknown...
```

There are 21 attributes, I want to split one column into 21 column.

`df['1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21'].apply(lambda x: pd.Series(x.split(';')))`

and it returns:

> KeyError: '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20'

What's the problem?

Comment: @Edchum - I think it is one column only.

Comment: @jezrael it's a terribly unclear question but you're right

Comment: Can you edit your question as it's unclear, can you make it clear what the raw data is, your code to read the data and create your df, and what the desired output is

Comment: What is `print (df.columns.tolist())` ?

Answer (score 3):

I think you missing `sep=';'` argument in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html), because by default `sep=','`.

But if need split first column by `;`, use [`str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iloc.html) for selecting first column:

```
print (df.iloc[:,0].str.split(';', expand=True))
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. and then I can use rename function to rename every column's name

Comment: Yes it is one solution. But maybe better is use assigning by list of column names `df.columns = [col1, col2, col3...col21]`.